# ¿En que estoy mal al llamar a la funcion?

Tags: c++, array, funcion

Al intentar llamar a la función con el array N[] dentro de los paréntesis no me lo permite (línea 22), ¿pueden decirme la razón y como solucionarlo?

Puede que este utilizando el tipo de función equivocado pero aún no me queda muy claro la diferencia entre ellos.

**Pongo el problema por si es necesario para darse una idea**:

> Escribir 2 funciones que reciban 3 números, una que muestre 3 números ordenados de manera ascendente y otra que muestre 3 números ordenados de manera descendente.
>
> En el `main()` deberás leer los 3 números enteros y un menú con 3 opciones:
>
> 1. Ordenar ascendentemente,
> 2. Ordenar descendentemente y
> 3. Salir del programa.
>
> Según la opción seleccionada es la función que se ejecutará.

De antemano gracias.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int A(int N[]);
int D(int N[]);

int main(){
    int N[3], r, arr;
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<"Ingrese un numero"<<endl;
        cin>>N[i];
       
    }
    
    cout<<"1-.Orden ascendente\n";
    cout<<"2-.Orden descendente\n";
    cout<<"3-.Finalizar programa\n";
    cin>>r;
    switch(r){
        case 1:A(N[i]);
        case 2:D(N[i]);
        case 3: return 0;
        deafult: return main();
    }
    return 0;
}

int A(int N[]){
    int aux=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(N [ j ] > N [ j + 1 ]){
                aux = N[j];
                N[j]=N[j+1];
                N[j]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        cout<<N[i]<<" ";
    }
}

int D(int N[]){
    int aux=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            if(N [ j ] > N [ j + 1 ]){
                aux = N[j];
                N[j]=N[j+1];
                N[j]=aux;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=2;i>=0;i--){
        cout<<N[i]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la interfaz de la página no muestra números de línea, así que no sabemos cuál es la línea 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tus funciones `A` y `D` tienen la siguiente firma:

```
int A(int N[]);
int D(int N[]);
```

Reciben un parámetro de tipo `int[]` es decir: una formación<sup>1</sup> de enteros (`int`), pero al llamar a las funciones en lugar de una formación les pasas un entero:

```
        case 1:A(N[i]);
//               ^^^^ <-- i-ésimo elemento de N
        case 2:D(N[i]);
//               ^^^^ <-- i-ésimo elemento de N
```

Muy probablemente lo que querías hacer es esto:

```
        case 1:A(N);
//               ^ <-- formación N
        case 2:D(N);
//               ^ <-- formación N
```

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

1. Si tu formación va a ser de tamaño fijo, puedes usar un alias para mejorar la legibilidad y la seguridad de tu código:

   ```
   using tres_int = int[3];

   int A(tres_int &N);
   int D(tres_int &N);

   int main(){
       tres_int N, r, arr;

       for (int &numero : N) {
           cout << "Ingrese un numero" << endl;
           cin >> numero;
       }

       ...
   ```

   Eso además (como puedes ver) te permite usar el `for` de rango, también tienes la opción de usar [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), con las mismas ventajas:

   ```
   using tres_int = std::array<int, 3>;
   ```
2. Si no usas `break` para marcar el final de una etiqueta de `switch`, se ejecutarán todas las etiquetas siguientes:

   ```
   switch(r){
       case 1:A(N[i]); break;
   //                  ~~~~~ <-- Sin esto, se ejecuta el case 1, 2 y 3
       case 2:D(N[i]); break;
   //                  ~~~~~ <-- Sin esto, se ejecuta el case 2 y 3
       case 3: return 0; break;
   //                    ~~~~~ <-- Aquí no haría falta break, pero no está de más.
       deafult: return main();
   }
   ```

   Además, la etiqueta de la opción por defecto es `default` no *`deafult`*.
3. Está **EXPLÍCITAMENTE PROHIBIDO** por la documentación del lenguaje C++ llamar a la función `main`. La función `main` sólo debe ser llamada por el sistema operativo, si quieres que un código se repita no llames de nuevo al programa entero:

   ```
   do {
       cout << "1-.Orden ascendente\n"
               "2-.Orden descendente\n"
               "3-.Finalizar programa\n";
       cin >> r;
       switch(r){
           case 1: A(N[i]); break;
           case 2: D(N[i]); break;
       }
   } while (r == 1 || r == 2);
   ```

   Además, no hay necesidad de llamar tres veces seguidas a `std::cout` para imprimir tres líneas, cualquier llamada consecutiva a `std::cout` puede ser transformada en una sola llamada.
4. Tus funciones `A` y `D` están declaradas para devolver un entero (`int`) pero no devuelven nada. Haz que devuelvan un valor o si no necesitas que devuelvan nada decláralas con retorno `void`.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda me sirvio mucho, tmbn me has ayudado en otras ocasiones y se agradece tu tiempo.